# Salesforce Server-To-Server API authentication

Tags: rest-api, api, oauth2, authentication

I'm writing a python application which shows some metrics about an organization.
However, I'm running into two problems:

1. There are no service accounts - I need to fetch information from Salesforce without acting as a specific user. With Google API there is the concept of a `service account` which has access to any resource + can be delegate any identity.
2. OAuth authentication flow requires user redirection - I run my app on an EC2 container and all the fetching are done in the background, I can't have users having to sign-in using their Salesforce account any time they access the service. I would like to have a token of an administrator/service account in another way besides the redirection method. I came across this [question & answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127218/server-to-server-jwt-authentication-certificate-management) but I couldn't figure out how to use it in my application.

Comment: Setting aside my answer for a moment, have you considered using a [Salesforce Site](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_overview.htm&type=5)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the [JWT Bearer OAuth 2.0 flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) is the way to go here.

There is some setup involved (you need to generate/use an X509 certificate, use the user-agent or web-server flows to authorize once), but after you do that the JWT flow can run in a headless environment (such as AWS).

I went into some pretty fine detail in [authentication using jwt](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/201636/authentication-using-jwt/201648) about how to use the JWT flow (the example is in Apex, but should be commented thoroughly enough to make a python implementation pretty easy).